# Linking excel with c#

Tags: c#, excel

The situation is as follows -
I'd like to make a very simple program in C# using an Excel spreadsheet.
The program would contain 2 text boxes where values can be entered, a label would then return the value corresponding to the respective row in Excel.

I have an Excel spreadsheet set up with three rows where I'd like to extract the information from.

First two rows are the parameters the third one holds the information I want to be printed out if the first two correspond to the given data.

Example:
If column 1 equals A and column 2 equals B then return answer corresponding to that respective row.

A B info01 |
A C info02 |
B A info03 |
B B info04

I want to enter value B and value A and have the program return info03

Hence that in the spreadsheet the returning line contains an index formula that already returns the information if first two conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a look at OpenXml SDK [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx). It'll allow you to read/edit Office documents quite easily and it's free.

Comment: I'll have a look at the OpenXML SDK. Thank you.